# Is it safe to keep C++ pointers in C#?

Tags: c#, c++, pointers

I'm currently working on some C#/C++ code which makes use of invoke. In the C++ side there is a std::vector full of pointers each identified by index from the C# code, for example a function declaration would look like this:

```
void SetName(char* name, int idx)
```

But now I'm thinking, since I'm working with pointers couldn't I sent to C# the pointer address itself then in code I could do something like this:

```
void SetName(char*name, int ptr)
{
   ((TypeName*)ptr)->name = name;
}
```

Obviously that's a quick version of what I'm getting at (and probably won't compile).

Would the pointer address be guaranteed to stay constant in C++ such that I can safely store its address in C# or would this be too unstable or dangerous for some reason?

Comment: Just to clarify: You know that the above code will compile in C# only if it is inside a `unsafe` block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, no problem.  Native memory allocations never move so storing the pointer in an IntPtr on the C# side is fine.  You need some kind of pinvoked function that returns this pointer, then

```
[DllImport("something.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
void SetName(IntPtr vector, string name, int index);
```

Which intentionally lies about this C++ function:

```
void SetName(std::vector<std::string>* vect, const char* name, int index) {
    std::string copy = name;
    (*vect)[index] = copy;
}
```

Note the usage of *new* in the C++ code, you have to *copy* the string.  The passed *name* argument points to a buffer allocated by the pinvoke marshaller and is only valid for the duration of the function body.  Your original code cannot work.  If you intend to return pointers to vector<> elements then be *very* careful.  A vector re-allocates its internal array when you add elements.  Such a returned pointer will then become invalid and you'll corrupt the heap when you use it later.  The exact same thing happens with a C# List<> but without the risk of dangling pointers.

Comment: By the way, that use of `new` is totally wrong in C++. It should just be `vect[index] = name;`. And I'm not even sure if pretending that a pointer is really a reference is even safe.

Comment: Fixed.  Demonstrating the copying of the string was rather important.  And yes, it is safe.

Comment: That's not really what I would define as *better*. More like, you've exchanged a problem that the compiler will tell you is wrong for a problem that you will only find out when you get heap corruption because raw pointers are horrendously unsafe and you double deleted it by accident or leaked it. Anyone who can read basic C++ would store `std::vector<std::string>` and just do `vect[index] = name;` and know that it constitutes a copy. At least use a smart pointer or something. Please. Putting up bad code like that as an example is teaching other people wrong things.

Comment: Sigh, please edit the code snippet so that you're happy *and* demonstrates the copying.

Comment: Here. Extremely explicit for you.

Answer (score 7):

In C#, you don't need to use a pointer here, you can just use a plain C# string.

```
[DllImport(...)]
extern void SetName(string name, int id);
```

This works because the default behavior of strings in p/invoke is to use `MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)`, which converts to a C-style char*. You can mark each argument in the C# declaration explicitly if it requires some other way of being marshalled, eg, `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]`, for an arg that uses a 2-byte per character string.

The only reason to use pointers is if you need to retain access to the data pointed to after you've called the function. Even then, you can use `out` parameters most of the time.

You can p/invoke basically anything without requiring pointers at all (and thus without requiring unsafe code, which requires privileged execution in some environments).

Answer (score 1):

I think it's stable till you command C++ code and perfectly aware what he does, and other developers that work on the same code know about that danger too.

So by my opinion, it's not very secure way of architecture, and I would avoid it as much as I can.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

The C# GC moves things, but the C++ heap does not move anything- a pointer to an allocated object is *guaranteed* to remain valid until you `delete` it. The best architecture for this situation is just to send the pointer to C# as an IntPtr and then take it back in C++.

It's certainly a vastly, incredibly better idea than the incredibly BAD, HORRIFIC integer cast you've got going there.

Comment: C# GC doesn't move strings though.

Comment: @Grozz - it most certainly does, not every string is interned.